# In Yahoo Pipes, how to remove a field?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have a Yahoo Pipe running on my site, [Romneyomics](http://Romneyomics.org) and it's fed with feeds from both Delicious as well as Topsy. 
The Delicious feed offers no 'description' field, but the Topsy does, and instead of just a link there's a duplicate line of details.

[image]

The image here should show the issue I am having, top links are how I want this to look, the lower two have 'descriptions' I'd like to strip out.

A similar answer here didn't quite answer the question. If it did, I'm not understanding it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For now, there is no module to remove certain fields. Here are alternatives.

1. [image: Rename Module]
   Set a meaningless name to a field with Rename.
2. [image: Loop, Item Builder Module]
   Keep certain fields, and remove any other fields with Item Builder and Loop.

   In this example, all fields but title and link are removed.

Comment: Much thanks. In the end, since the feed on the site was showing description, I named it something else as you suggested (first suggestion above). For whatever reason, it took a while to ripple through, so I didn't realize that was a good solution till hours later.

Comment: can you make an example pipe? I tried the second one but it's returning 0 items on the debugger.

Comment: @hermione Sorry. The second example image was wrong, and I've corrected it.By mistake, I set `item.title` and `item.link` in the left parts of Item Builder. In this case, a name of the field will be the value of the left part. If `item.title` is `YahooPipes` and `item.link` is "http://pipes.yahoo.com/", the result is `{"YahooPipes": "YahooPipes", "http://pipes.yahoo.com/": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/"}`. And, when all of the left part are undefined, 0 items are returned.

Comment: When I try and rename `item.title` to `__null` or `item.nothing` then render the pipe as RSS, I get `<title><img&hellip;</title>`. I just want the title to be blank. Any ideas?